# NSButton action not working from custom NSView

Tags: swift, nsbutton, nsscrollview

I have my Push button in subview called AddContactViewController

And I'm showing it in ScrollView in another ViewController called AddContactScrollViewController.

I'm setting action for my button in AddContactViewController
But, when I click my button nothing happens.

Here are the screenshots my IB. And below is the code.

Main view controller
[image]

SubView
[image]

```
import Cocoa  


class AddContactScrollViewController: NSViewController {  

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!  

    var contentView: NSView?  


    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  

        contentView = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 1123))  
        contentView!.wantsLayer = true  
        contentView!.layer?.backgroundColor =  NSColor.clear.cgColor  

        let tempVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "addAddress")) as! AddAddressViewController  
        vc.view.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0))  
        vc.view.setFrameSize(NSSize(width: 1200, height: 1123))  
        vc.view.wantsLayer = true  

        contentView!.addSubview(vc.view)  
        scrollView.documentView = contentView  

        // scroll to the top  
        if let documentView = scrollView.documentView {  
            documentView.scroll(NSPoint(x: 0, y: documentView.bounds.size.height))  
        }    
    }  

    override func viewDidAppear() {  


    }  


} 


import Cocoa  

class AddContactVeiwController: NSViewController {  


    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()   
    }  


    @IBAction func addPhoneButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {  
        print("phone button  clicked")  
    }
```

Comment: `tempVC`/`vc` is released unless you keep a strong reference.

Comment: You have also overridden viewDidAppear() without calling super.viewDidAppear() inside it.  That's not recommended. Should always call super in these lifecycle methods.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes YU FENG. Declaring vc in viewDidLoad creates a problem as you leave viewDidLoad, the vc doesn't exists anymore. Declare the vc in the class, solves the problem.